# hyperbolic geometry and affine transformations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A very famous geometer recently commented to me that "hyperbolic geometries are the only geometries invariant under affine transformations". It is unclear to me what this comment even means. Can someone clarify this for me. Some type of reference would also be nice.

Comment: This statement does make much sense, I think you should ask the "very famous geometer" for a clarification.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  meant "does not make much sense".

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a guess:

1. First, we need to define "geometry": I will assume that it means a complete simply-connected Riemannian manifold of constant curvature $0$ or $\pm 1$. (This, of course, excludes many other geometries.)
2. Next, given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$, a diffeomorphism $f: M\to M$ is called *affine* if it preserves $\nabla$. Similarly, $f$ is *projective* if it sends unparameterized  geodesics to unparameterized geodesics. In particular, each affine transformation is projective.
3. Now, among all n-dimensional  geometries, both the Euclidean space and the unit sphere admit projective transformations  which are not isometric, but the hyperbolic n-space, does not admit such. On the other hand, each affine transformation of $S^n$ is an isometry. Thus, my conjecture is that "famous geometer" meant **projective** instead of **affine** and what he had in mind is:

If $(M,g)$ is a complete simply-connected Riemannian manifold of constant curvature, for which the group of projective transformations equals the group of isometric transformations, then $(M,g)$ has negative curvature; in other words, it is a hyperbolic space.

**Edit.** As requested, here is a sketch of a proof that every affine transformation of the round sphere $S^n$ is an isometry ($n\ge 2$). First of all, let $P(S^n)$ denote the group of projective transformations of $S^n$, i.e. maps sending (unparameterized) geodesics to (unparameterized) geodesics. Let $PGL(n+1,R)$ denote the projectivization of the general linear group $GL(n+1,R)$; this group is acting on the projective space $R P^{n}$ by projective transformations (where the Riemannian manifold $R P^{n}$ is the quotient of $S^n$  by the antipodal involution). According to the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry (FTPG),   $PGL(n+1,R)$ is exactly the group of projective transformations of Riemannian manifold $R P^{n}$. Each element of $PGL(n+1,R)$ lifts to a self-diffeomorphism of $S^n$; I will use the notation $G$ to denote the group consisting of such lifts: Algebraically speaking it is a central extension of $PGL(n+1,R)$:
$$
1\to {\mathbb Z}_2\to G\to PGL(n+1,R)\to 1. 
$$
With a bit of work, using FTPG, one proves that $G$ is exactly the group of projective transformations of $S^n$. Thus, the problem reduces to proving that the only affine transformations of $RP^n$ are the isometries of $RP^n$, i.e. the subgroup $PO(n+1)<PGL(n+1,R)$. We will use the SVD, the singular value decomposition: Every element of   $PGL(n+1,R)$ can be written as a product $kak'$, with $k, k'\in PO(n+1)$ and $a$ the projectivization of a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries. Thus, the problem reduces to proving that if such $a$ is an affine transformation of $RP^n$ then $a=id$. Every such $a$ preserves some projective lines in $RP^n$, projectivizations of coordinate 2-planes in $R^{n+1}$. If $a\ne id$ then it acts by a non-identity map on one of these projective lines $L$, fixing precisely two points $p, q$ on $L$. But, regarding $L$ as a parameterized geodesic, it is clear that $a: L\to L$ cannot send such a parameterized geodesic to a parameterized geodesic (the speed of $a(L)$ at $p$ will be different from the speed of $a(L)$ at $q$).

Comment: The geometer might have as well been referring to projective transformations in the same loose way Dietrich seemed to be referring  to the projective transformations between points in the disk boundary (the real projective line) in Klein-Beltrami projective model of hyperbolic space as the invariance of the 2-dimensional disk to affine transformations of the disk to itself. So depending on the dimensionality one wishes to concentrate on the projective transformations can be called affine transformations in n+1.

Comment: @Walterscott: You as well could be right, but in my answer I was trying to explain where did "the only geometries" come from in the statement by a "famous geometer". I am well aware of the fact that the Lorentzian model provides a way to regard hyperbolic isometries as linear transformations, but this does not explain "the only" statement. Isometries of both euclidean and spherical geometries are clearly affine, thus, thus "afineness" in this sense cannot be a distinguishing feature of the hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: And your explanation is correct. I just suggested a way in wich the claim in the question could actually be referring(misleadingly in its use of the term "affine") to projective transformations as it is the only way the "famous geometer" could be right. The fact is that projective transformations are almost always explained in the context of projective spaces associated to a vector space. Even hyperbolic geometry doesn't scape this and it is generally represented in scale invariant  models like the Klein or the hyperboloid models that are ultimately based on  linearity rather than intrinsic.

Comment: Do you have a simple reason or a reference for the stated claim that only affine transformations of the sphere are isometries?

Comment: @ViditNanda Not simple, but it is an application of the Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry.

Comment: @ViditNanda: See the edit.

Comment: @moishekohan this is great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One can define hyperbolic geometry as the study of points and chords of a disk $D$ invariant under affine transformations of $D$ to itself; see Klein's disk model of non-Euclidean geometry. However, there are also others models of hyperbolic space, e.g., the Poincare model. 
The remark could be related to Klein's disk model of hyperbolic geometry, but I am not sure.
The "very famous geometer" might not agree.
One would need a bit more context, I think. A good reference here are excellent articles and lecture notes of W. Goldman on projective, affine and hyperbolic geometry on manifolds.

(link:http://www.math.umd.edu/~wmg/ and more in particular  http://www.math.umd.edu/~wmg/pgom.pdf )